# Indiana State Tax Returns | Did not receive 1099s

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, capital-gain

I have not received 1099s (INT, DIV, B) from my broker this year. I have to file Indiana State taxes by paper. Since, I do not have 1099's to attach what should I send in place of that? I have some online Income distribution from my broker. Can I attach print outs of that?

Answer (score 1):

Were you supposed to receive them? Or were they lost/misplaced?

If the amounts are too low they don't have to issue a 1099. But if they were lost you may be able to get a replacement.

Are they available on the website? Many 1099s, 1098's, and W-2's I see only exist as a PDF file. The pdf can of course be printed.

Comment: They did not hold taxes for me that year. What determines that whether I was supposed to receive them or not?

No they were not available on the website too till 40 hours ago atleast.

Comment: In general the 1099-int and 1099Div  only needs to be generated if the payment is $10 or above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mail in most 1099s. They are a reference for you to know what your bank/brokerage has reported to the IRS.

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed out, that for paper filings certain documents with withheld tax needs to be submitted. [The IRS requests that a copy of 1099-R be submitted](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm140228281449216).

If you have a online account, you should be able to download them. Otherwise you should call and get a copy.

If you bank/brokerage made a mistake with income types (i.e. capital gain vs return on capital), they will mail/generate out a corrected form or you'll have to follow up with them.

Do realize that if the amount reported on any 1099-INT or 1099-DIV is below $10 USD, the bank/brokerage/mutual fund isn't required to generate the form.

Comment: I don't know for Indiana, but for the states I have lived in, and also Federally, _on a paper return_ you do attach 1099's (and W-2's) that _show withholding_ -- which a _broker_ 1099 usually would not, but some others like pension and gambling often would.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, updated text.